# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I try to attach a debugger to my Azure server, I get this error:

[image]

I already installed Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2015. Any idea why this happens?